# Could be in Optional really anything

Tags: java, option-type

I found implemented this code (method where this part of code is used is returning `Optional<File>`, this part of code had to be added for verification if values are correct and case can be saved):

```
if (!CaseChecker.checkValues(case)) {
    return Optional.of(new File("FALSE"));
}
```

When I asked the person, why he is returning something like this. The answer was "Optional can contain any value". To be honest I don't agree with this, because type of Optional is for some reason. So I wanted to confirm if Optional can be really anything and if yes, then what's the reason to write Optional type.

Comment: Method is returning empty optional for different ifs. And then when he is using returned value he needs to distinguish it. So instead of use check again he is doing this and then handling situation when it returned Optional with File "False".

Comment: That's definitely an abuse of the type system, but whether it's `Optional`  that's being abused here or `File` is up for discussion IMO.

Comment: Yeah, more abused is File type, but then in the end explicitly also Optional IMO. So kinda both are abused?

Comment: This is the most wonderfully bizarre thing I have heard in a long time! It can't be easy to work with people like that. Maybe it keeps work interesting thought, you can never know what they will come up with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole point of `Optional` is to avoid the situation where you return a bogus value (like null, or like returning -1 from `String.indexOf` in order to indicate it didn't find anything), putting the responsibility on the caller to know what is bogus and to know to check for it. Returning Optional lets the caller know it needs to check whether a valid result came back, and it takes away the burden of the caller code needing to know what return values aren't valid.

`Optional` was never meant as a wrapper for a bogus value.

And yes you can return anything. The api doesn't stop you from doing nonsensical things.

Also consider that flatMap doesn't know what to do with this weird thing, it will treat the contents as nonempty. So now how you can use this value is limited. You have a multistage validation process where it might be something you can handle with operations chained together using flatMap, but this fake file has made that harder. It's limited your options.

Return [`Optional.empty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#empty()) if you don't have a valid value to return.

Comment: Thanks. I would say "And yes you can return anything. The api doesn't stop you from doing nonsensical things." is more than enough.

Comment: I think, the `Optional` is entirely irrelevant here. The question is, whether using a value like `new File("FALSE")` for flagging anything, is a reasonable thing. Obviously, it’s not, as the caller has to do either, assume all files named `FALSE` as invalid or use the existence of the file as a flag value, and either case will break in some way if the user just creates an actual file named `FALSE`. So it is unreasonable in the first place and doesn’t get better when wrapping it in an `Optional`.

Comment: I was asking mainly about Optional. Creation of `new File("FALSE")` and trying to somehow pretend it's boolean is strange/incorrect at first glance from my point of view.

Comment: But that’s the point, the statement “Optional can contain any (non-null) value” is factually correct. But that doesn’t justify the existence of a bogus value. That’s like asking someone “why do you run a red light?” and getting the response “red is a primary color”. Well, that’s a technically correct statement, but not a justification for the questioned action.